# Skinning rigged model - Fine adjustments in Weight Painting for twisted skin

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, pose-mode

I made a very basic human body mesh and want to make my very first character animation with it. I rigged the model and when I made the rig the parent of the mesh I chose the option to apply automatic weights. When I move the head and legs in Pose Mode I am pretty happy with which parts of the Mesh are affected. But the **arms** are a desaster: I modelled them stretched out and when I try to bring them down in Pose Mode there is too much going on in the chest area, when I move the lower part of the arm the area around the "elbow" the "flesh/skin" is twisted; same is true for the hands and wrists. So I tried to adjust weights in Weight Painting Mode around these bones (and also tried to remove Faces from the Vertex Groups) but then I ended up getting this:

[image: Weight is too low]

The problem I think is that I cannot subtract weight in small amounts, I can choose my brush to be just 10px but it will always be a very huge area (like a whole vertex) be selected while painting. Can that be more fine-tunded somehow? I ended up selecting my Mesh and applying weight from bones again. What can I do to not have twisted "flesh/skin" and to have the right (fine) amount of weight in the chest area influenced by the upper arm bones? This is my **[blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2FsEJdefonnZXBJVUtDS1hNOTQ)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract weight in small amounts, but it will still affect a large area, because the weight is per-vertex.

To change how much you add/subtract/etc., change the Strength slider in the left (<kbd>T</kbd>) panel.

As for exactly how much weight you need, I can't help you there. (:

(With your particular model, it's so low-poly I might just tweak the weights manually, from the Vertex Weights section in the right (<kbd>N</kbd>) panel.)

Comment: Ah ok I could have concluded that .. that the weight painting is of course vertex-wise. Thanks.. Ok and because my model is that lowpoly, .. now it makes sense :-) Vertices will not bend ^^ I think I'll try to make it a bit less lowpoly and give it another shot, maybe also by assigning the weight vertex-wise in properties panel ..

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck!

Comment: For future (also bloody beginner) readers of my post: To achieve the less low poly mesh and add more vertices to do a more finetuned weight painting/assigning I added and applied a Subdivision Surface Modifier to my model .. Now I still have to figure out which weights / distribution of weights around bone are best to have a smooth loooking skin which does so twist or fold

Comment: Yeah, that's the hard part. (:

Comment: BTW, if you just want a human model, there's a great tool called [MakeHuman](http://makehuman.org) that allows you to create a (fully rigged) human model just by tweaking sliders!